# Testing Fuzzy Logic

Tags: java, eclipse, networking, network-programming, fuzzy-logic

I have a problem to testing my fuzzy logic on Java programming either right or wrong.

Do you have any simple source code to test it.

May you share to me, please.

Kindly need your help.

Thank you so much.

Best Regards,

Deni Y.

Answer (score 2):

The codez:

```
public class FuzzyLogicTester
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int a = 1 + 1;  // \u000a\u0061\u002b\u002b;
    System.out.println(a);
  }
}
```